# Load page on click if not loaded before

Tags: jquery, pageload

please tell me how can i stop loading a page onclick if the page is already loaded?

```
$(".Tab_heading:first-child").live('click',function(){
$.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: "relatedInfo.action",
            data: $(".relatedinfo_wrapper"),
            success: relatedInfodesktop
        });

$(".Tab_heading").removeClass("tabselected");
$(this).addClass("tabselected");
$(".RelService_wrapper").show();
$(".DepService_wrapper").hide();

});
```

Tab_heading acts as tabs(there are two tab link class="Tab_heading")
if the user click on the heading the page is loaded
but again if the user clicks on the heading and if the page is already loaded, it shouldn't load again(GET http:xxxxxxx/relatedInfo.action --- i should not get this)
please provide a solution

Comment: Unless you're using an old (pre-1.7) version of jQuery, you should be using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of the deprecated [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Comment: there's no problem with .live() function

Comment: It's a friendly suggestion to use the most up-to-date API, because `.live()` is being removed from jQuery in favor of `.on()`.

Comment: _.on()_ is not supported for jquery iam using

Comment: I concur that it's worth putting in the effort to update to the latest version of jQuery. It will make your life much less complicated and much more efficient. It might take some time and effort (for example, replacing jquery-ui tab features with Twitter's bootstrap tabs), but the end result is well worth every effort. I just finished doing this on an older project, and while it was a headache, the project is better for it and even runs and loads faster.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just add some check before run AJAX. For example, as I see from your code you remove and add some classes. So if your ajax responce was already loaded you will have different styles in page. So try something like this

```
$(".Tab_heading:first-child").live('click',function(){
if ($(this).hasClass("tabselected")){ do nothing}
else{$.ajax({you get the rest})}
}
```

Comment: Excellent approach Mykola; however, instead of checking, prevent the code from ever running again by simply removing the event. That way, if another click happens, no check occurs, not even once.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the event once loaded; waiting to disable the event until a user clicks may not be the best solution.  JQuery provides the .load() function; simply select the element that will contain your ajax-loaded content, and call

```
$('#my_loading_element').load(function() {$(".Tab_heading:first-child").off('click')});
```

on it. That will remove the click event after the element has been loaded. Or, if the element is always loaded through ajax, you can put this:

```
$(".Tab_heading:first-child").off('click');
```

in your success function to disengage the event.

It seems to me that if the data starts to load even before the user clicks on something, you should probably not be doing the ajax call at all and simply put the content in there from the server side; if, however, you have to have the ajax call and it has to be triggered on click, you can also use a third option where you disengage the event on the first click, so that all subsequent clicks do nothing (for example, when a user clicks and triggers ajax once, then clicks again before it finishes, then again and again... buggy code would put the content in multiple times). Your code would look a bit more like this:

```
$(".Tab_heading:first-child").live('click',function(){
    $(this).off('click');
    $.ajax({
    ...
    });
});
```

This is probably the best option in your case; make the ajax call trigger once on click but never again.

EDIT

```
$(".Tab_heading:first-child").live('click',function(){
    $(this).off('click');
    $.ajax({
    ...
        success: function() {
            $(".Tab_heading:first-child").on('click', function() {
                //open the tab here
            }).click();
        } //no trailing comma for IE compatibility
    });
});
```

That last call to .click() is for convenience so the user doesn't have to click on the tab twice to open it.

One last thing: if the jquery you use is not 1.7 or greater, you should update for many reasons. The newer versions are easier to use, more intuitive, more efficient, less clumsy, and may have security features that are essential to serious web developers. Even if it takes ages to convert a site over, it's worth the effort.

Comment: If i do this, the on click of this, the tab content also wont open

Comment: This is probably because you have multiple events triggering on click; if you only have those two events (the tab opening, and the tab loading) that trigger on click, you may want to put your tab opening code inside of the tab loading code. See my edit.

Comment: only events on click is tab open n content load from the action provided, so if i try _.off()_ then the user cannot click and the tab wont open and since iam using jquery 1.4 _.on()_ wont work :(

Comment: Again, see my edit. You don't want to open a tab before the content is loaded, so what you do is load it, then add the click event in again so that the tab can get opened, and trigger the click event using jQuery. Sorry that my edit wasn't finished when you read the post; it's at the very end.

Comment: ...And neither will .off(). You'll have to find the equivalent functionality for your version, but the approach is still the same.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code where you can check the variable before loading the page.

```
var loaded = false;

$(".Tab_heading:first-child").live('click',function(){
if(!loaded){
$.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: "relatedInfo.action",
        data: $(".relatedinfo_wrapper"),
        success: relatedInfodesktop
    });

$(".Tab_heading").removeClass("tabselected");
$(this).addClass("tabselected");
$(".RelService_wrapper").show();
$(".DepService_wrapper").hide();
});
}
}
function relatedInfodesktop(response){
//your code here
loaded = true;
}
```